# Python requests does not response correct html

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would really appreciate if someone could help me with a problem. I am trying to scrape website  https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/index/xxx as xxx being stock symbol. For example https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/index/spx. My code worked more than year but for some reason does not work anymore as requesting a page will return some weird part on html. As you can see the webpage is more complicated than my request result. I also tried beautifulsoup and so on as I though that problem is about javascript, but I get a same result.

Part of code (with requests):

```
url = "https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/index/spx"
page = requests.get(url)
print(page.content)
```

Result:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<link href="about:blank" rel="shortcut icon"/>
<script     src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json3/3.3.2/json3.min.js">            </script>
<script src="https://resources.kasadapolyform.io/kpfp.js"></script>
<script src="/149e9513-01fa-4fb0-aad4-566afd725d1b/2d206a39-8ed7-437e-a3be-    862e0f06eea3/fingerprint/script/kpf.js?url=/149e9513-01fa-4fb0-aad4-566afd725d1b/2d206a39-8ed7-437e-a3be-862e0f06eea3/fingerprint&amp;token=46f828d0-bb88-fcd0-c7ad-47f18d3c13a2"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: Looks like they updated their website to load data via JS rather than server sided. Ain't nothing you can do about that except use Selenium.

Comment: Don't do that.  The content is not yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Jaxi, the html returned implies that the page is almost entirely rendered by JavaScript instead of HTML.

In order to work around this you will need to use a tool which will allow you to run the JavaScript and then use that HTML.

One example is [Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/), which is used in UI testing.

Another is Kenneth Reitz's (the original author of the `requests` package) package [requests_html](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests-html). This will use the Chromium browser under the hood and render the page for you. From the README:

```
>>> r = session.get('http://python-requests.org')

>>> r.html.render()

>>> r.html.search('Python 2 will retire in only {months} months!')['months']
'<time>25</time>'
```

As a side note, as mentioned by ewindes, you should always be careful and make sure that the sites you are scraping permit web scraping. If not as a matter of legality, than one of courtesy.

Comment: At least I know what's the cause of the problem now. I also tried requests_html before put came a cross know problem "pyppeteer.errors.NetworkError: Protocol Error: Cannot find context with specified id None"

Will try with selenium soon. 

I only scraping the prices from there.

Comment: I got thing working with selenium and also the previous code with minor changes in xpath as https://www.marketwatch.com/search?q=xxx looks like does not run so much JS

Thank you very much